# Remote Access MariaDB and mySQL database

Tags: mysql, database, raspberry-pi, mariadb, remote-access

I'm trying to solve a problem that is driving me crazy. I have installed a MariaDB server, PHPMyAdmin, SQL, Apache2, and PHP on my Raspberry Pi 3. Everything works locally, but I would like to be able to connect to my database from outside. The reason for this is that I have uploaded a small database to freehosting.com, and despite everything, I'm getting an error: "Connection to the database failed: Access denied for user 'admin'@'192.168.0.22' (using password: YES)". Needless to say, I have already tried everything.

I have opened port 3306 in my router settings.
I have opened the port in the RP3 settings.
I have changed the value of the bind address from 127.0.0.0 to 0.0.0.0. I have also tried commenting it out with the "#" symbol, but the result remains the same.

Naturally, I have created a database account with all the permissions, privileges, and all hosts with the "%" symbol, and I have also tried creating an account with the host "192.168.0.22". I have tried changing the username, etc. I have even done a fresh reinstallation, but nothing works. I'm starting to think that there might be some block on their end.

Please help me.

I have opened port 3306 in my router settings.
I have opened the port in the RP3 settings.
I have changed the value of the bind address from 127.0.0.0 to 0.0.0.0. I have also tried commenting it out with the "#" symbol, but the result remains the same.

Comment: It's not clear from your question where your database is located, and where your MySql client code is located -- where you are trying to connect from. It is clear that there is a TCP/IP route from your client code to your database server, as it was able to present a password and have it rejected. Please [edit] your question to provide more details.